# Is there a way for watch apps to support only new apple watches (4 and above)?

Tags: ios, apple-watch, watchos

The title kind of says it all, I would like to develop an app only for new apple watches. The reason for this is that my app drains the battery of old apple watches really fast making it unusable and not meeting the energy efficiency requirement in appstore review.

Answer (score 0):

You can only restrict your app to newer watchOS versions, not Apple Watch hardware models.

Comment: I know about os restriction, but I was looking for a way to restrict hardware, on iphones there were some tricks for this. Anyway I think I will just disable the features that are consuming resources on old devices.